# How to make query string on Elastic Search/Open Search with proximity and parentheses?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I want to make a query where I need `crocodile` to be near to `luffy` or `crocodile` near to `robin`. But the query `crocodile AND (luffy OR robin)` is not exactly what I want because the maximum distance need to be 3, so I tried something like it(the default operator is set to AND):

`"crocodile (luffy OR robin)"~3`

But it not work. How can I achieve this purpose using these operators?
I dont want to use something like:

`"crocodile AND luffy "~3 OR "crocodile AND robin "~3`

Because It will turn my queries too long.

ES documentations talks about [avoid mixing fuzzines with wildcards](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#avoid-widlcards-fuzzy-searches), but I don't found nothin about proximity with parentheses.

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67987989/boolean-query-with-multiple-ors-in-a-proximity-search-using-lucene-syntax). As far as I know you cannot do mix proximity searches with boolean operators in Lucene queries. Your alternative is to use [span queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/span-queries.html) or [interval queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-intervals-query.html) which are meant exactly for that use case.